# Using data Frames to match times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, im struggling a little bit here. I'm trying to attach my flight log to some rsrp data and the flight log records at 0.1s and the data logger I was using was at 1s. What I'm now trying to do is since there a higher data rate, just at all points of a second I'm trying to fill it in with the same value when the time matches. There is a sample of my code below (Don't grill me to hard lol) and the output's.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlrd
import csv
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime
import xlsxwriter

count = 0
Excel_list1 = []
Lon = []
Lat = []
Time_F = []
Alt = []
RSRP = []
Time_R = []


AMT_Row=[]

Excel_path = r'C:/Users/' + os.getlogin() + '/Desktop/EE598/Excel'

for path in os.listdir(Excel_path):
    # check if current path is a file
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(Excel_path, path)):
        count += 1

#print('File count:', count)
Excel_list = os.listdir(Excel_path)
res = [sub[: -5] for sub in Excel_list]

Excel_list1.append(str(res))


print(Excel_list1[0])

for A in range(0, count):
    wb = load_workbook(Excel_path + '/' + Excel_list[0])
    sheet = wb.active
    AMT_Row.append((sheet.max_row))


for row in sheet['E2:E' + str(AMT_Row[A]) ]:
    x = (str([x.value for x in row]).replace("['",""))
    Lat.append(x)
for row in sheet['F2:F' + str(AMT_Row[A]) ]:
    x = (str([x.value for x in row]).replace("['",""))
    Lon.append(x)
for row in sheet['J2:J' + str(AMT_Row[A]) ]:
    x = (str([x.value for x in row]).replace("['",""))
    Alt.append(x)
for row in sheet['B2:B' + str(AMT_Row[A]) ]:
    x = (str([x.value for x in row]).replace("['",""))
    Time_F.append(x)




Excel_list2 = []


Excel_path = r'C:/Users/' + os.getlogin() + '/Desktop/EE598/Excel1'
count = 0












for path in os.listdir(Excel_path):
    # check if current path is a file
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(Excel_path, path)):
    count += 1
#print('File count:', count)
Excel_list = os.listdir(Excel_path)
res = [sub[: -5] for sub in Excel_list]

Excel_list2.append(str(res))




AMT_Row1=[]

for A in range(0, count):

    wb = load_workbook(Excel_path + '/signal_strength.xlsx' )
    sheet = wb.active
    AMT_Row1.append((sheet.max_row))

    for row in sheet['A2:A' + str(AMT_Row1[A]) ]:
        x = (str([x.value for x in row]).replace("['",""))
        Time_R.append(x)
    for row in sheet['B2:B' + str(AMT_Row1[A]) ]:
        x = (str([x.value for x in row]).replace("['",""))
        RSRP.append(x)




data_Flight = pd.DataFrame({'Longitude': Lon,
    'Latitude': Lat,
    'Altitude': Alt,
    'Time': Time_F
               })




data_RSRP = pd.DataFrame({'RSRP': RSRP,
    'Time_R': Time_R

               })
print(data_RSRP)
print(data_Flight)
```

Output RSRP:

```
           RSRP                                         Time_R
      0    [-70]  [datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 11, 11, 53, 11)]
      1    [-70]  [datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 11, 11, 53, 12)]
      2    [-67]  [datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 11, 12, 18, 49)]
      3    [-67]  [datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 11, 12, 18, 50)]
      4    [-67]  [datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 11, 12, 18, 51)]
      ..     ...                                            ...
      656  [-72]   [datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 11, 13, 1, 28)]
      657  [-72]   [datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 11, 13, 1, 29)]
      658  [-72]   [datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 11, 13, 1, 30)]
      659  [-72]   [datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 11, 13, 1, 31)]
      660  [-72]   [datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 11, 13, 1, 32)]

      [661 rows x 2 columns]
```

Output Flight Log:

```
                          Longitude  ...                                 Time
                0     [-78.7905912606503]  ...  [datetime.time(12, 54, 58, 220000)]
                1     [-78.7905912621039]  ...  [datetime.time(12, 54, 58, 320000)]
                2     [-78.7905912574604]  ...  [datetime.time(12, 54, 58, 420000)]
                3     [-78.7905912805402]  ...  [datetime.time(12, 54, 58, 520000)]
                4     [-78.7905913101142]  ...  [datetime.time(12, 54, 58, 630000)]
                ...                   ...  ...                                  ...
                3709  [-78.7906285839167]  ...   [datetime.time(13, 1, 13, 310000)]
                3710  [-78.7906285859315]  ...   [datetime.time(13, 1, 13, 410000)]
                3711  [-78.7906286887682]  ...   [datetime.time(13, 1, 13, 520000)]
                3712  [-78.7906286918899]  ...   [datetime.time(13, 1, 13, 620000)]
                3713  [-78.7906287873995]  ...   [datetime.time(13, 1, 13, 720000)]

                [3714 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: maybe first you should add column which has time 1s instead 0.1s - and maybe later use this column to `join()` another table (like in SQL)

Comment: pandas doc: [Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html)